# Twig hash and array in a single

Tags: twig

I want to have hash and array in a single. I mean this (that's in PHP but I want the same effect in Twig):

```
['class' => 'form-control', 'required']
```

As [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#literals) says it can be *nested* but it probably isn't what I want.

That's my part of Twig view:

```
{{ text('name', '', {'class': 'form-control', 1: 'required'}) }}
```

Am I forced to do this with integer index or is there any elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this in php:

```
var_dump(['class' => 'form-control', 'required']);
```

You will see that the index of "required" is 0 - not 1

```
array(2) {
  ["class"]=>
  string(12) "form-control"
  [0]=>
  string(8) "required"
}
```

So in Twig you need to do:

```
{{ text('name', '', {'class': 'form-control', 0: 'required'}) }}
```